# From where should I add settings that concern multiple websites

Tags: settings, admin

My application is used to modify settings for client CMS sites (ex: setting to enable a module etc)
There are multiple clients using this CMS.
When I add a new setting, it's automatically added for every single site.
There are two places I could add a new setting from:

1. The interface for editing these settings
2. An admin interface located somewhere else

My first thought was choice 1 as it seems logical to add a new item from the interface that allows you to edit the items.
On the other hand, this editing view concerns only one site, but we would be adding the setting to all the sites. Also you need admin privileges for creating new settings.

What would be the best choice here ? Thanks

Comment: No ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses something resembling your second choice. In WordPress Multisite environments there is a different dashboard for individual sites and if you are a "super admin" you have access to a dashboard for all of the network.

This network dashboard for example makes possible to add new plugins to every site on the network.

There are some problems on their approach, at least when used out of the box. It really isn't that clear whether you are modifying a single site or the whole network. Some color cues would probably do the trick.

Here is some more info on Multisite and network admin, with pictures: [Intro to WordPress and WordPress Multisite](http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/wordpress-wordpress-mu-and-wordpress-multisite)